# Deploy several wordpress instances with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

I am missing a feature in Kubernetes for horizontal scaling of "standalone" application (where you can assign one application to one user).

I would like to deploy several instances of Wordpress with kubernetes. 
Each instance should have its own environment and data and assigned to one user.

At first I thought about Statefullset but the problem is that when you delete one pod, you have to delete it in reverse order or all in parallel .. 
What if the 3rd user cancel the service and you want to delete only the third pod ?!

Deployments ?  Then I have to create one unique Pod for each user with their own volume !? Where is kubernetes added value there ..

Do you have any other better idea ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from a Slack user, StatefulSet should not be used in this case. 
It's better to use one different deployment for each user (wordpres-).